# Bitwise Operators ">>" and "<<"?

Tags: c++

Can somebody explain them to me and mainly help me understand >> and <<. I just started to study C++ and it's being used constantly in console input/output applications.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an example which depicts their usage?

Comment: @cpx `cout << "Hello World!";`
`int a; cin >> a;`

Comment: Those are definitely not bitwise operators, however you might want to see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not bitwise operators you are seeing there, rather the stream extraction and insertion operators.

http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Answer (score 2):

Those are stream operators - if you're using them for input/output. Bitwise operators are completely different.

Check out this link:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Overload/Overloadstreamoperator.htm